# Interceptor for http outbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Has sprint integration http outbound gateway has any configuration property to add interceptor into org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate ?

I want to intercept the httpRequest for adding  some security information in request (like interceptor property in ws-ouboundgatewy) ,But I could not see any interceptor configuration option in http outbound gateway?.

Do we have any other option  to achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject to the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` any custom `RestTemplate` bean using `rest-template` attribute on the first one.

But from other side I don't see any mentions for interceptor logic in the `RestTemplate`...

Comment: I could inject the restTemplate bean into Gateway. But am getting the below error org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: When providing a 'rest-template' reference, the 'message-converters' attribute is not allowed.
I am using message-converters' for marshalling and unmarshalling.
Spring-integration version 4.1.0

Comment: So, why just don't follow with the advice from that exception and just inject all your converters to that `restTemplate` bean?

Comment: Yes. Got it. Instead of rest template I have added header mapper which helps to set custom security header

Comment: Hi , I am facing a problem where injecting a RestTemplate might help me can you please show me some working code for injecting RestTemplete in <int-http:outbound-gateway> my question is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241595/getting-large-response-from-http-outbound-gateway-in-spring-integration