# Getting large response from Http Outbound Gateway in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to get response from Http Outbound Gateway. I have used `expected-response-type="java.lang.String"`. I am able to get data, data is string representation of XML, but data is large so I am getting only part of it, I am not able to find a way to get full data.

In documentation they have given example to use Multipart with Http Inbound Gateway their is no reference how to use Multipart in Http Outbound Gateway.

I also came to know that http outbound uses `RestTemplate` to make calls but I was not able to figure out how can I inject my own `RestTemplate` in Http Outbound Gateway.

Is their any way in XML configuration where I can insert some configuration and I may get full response in Http Outbound Gateway.

just for refrence here is my Http Outbound Gateway:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestGatewayChannel"
        url="${myurl}" http-method="GET" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"  
            </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```